# Laravel FatalErrorException in SerializableClosure.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting the following error in my Laravel app, could someone help me troubleshoot this exception?

> FatalErrorException in SerializableClosure.php(153) : eval()'d code
>   line 2: Call to a member function getOwnerEmail() on array

My getter is in a Notices.php model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notice extends Model {

    /**
     * A notice is created by a user
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * Get the email address of the notice
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getOwnerEmail()
    {
        return $this->user->email;
    }
```

**NoticesController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Provider;
use App\Notice;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NoticesController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request)

        {
            $notice = $this->createNotice($request);

            \Mail::queue('emails.dmca', compact('notice'), function($message) use ($notice) {
                $message->from($notice->getOwnerEmail())
                        ->to($notice->getRecipientEmail())
                        ->subject('DMCA Notice');
            });

            return redirect('notices');

        }

    public function createNotice(Request $request)
    {
        $notice = session()->get('dmca') + ['template' => $request->input('template')];

        \Auth::user()->notices()->create($notice);

        return $notice;

    }

    public function create()
    {
        // get list of providers
        $providers = Provider::lists('name', 'id');

        return view('notices.create', compact('providers'));

    }
```

Comment: The `Notice` object you are using is not a model object, it's an array, How did you get the `$notice` variable, show it's use.

Comment: Show `createNotice` please.

Comment: `$notice = $this->createNotice($request);` returns an `array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public function createNotice(Request $request)
{
    $notice = session()->get('dmca') + ['template' => $request->input('template')];

    return \Auth::user()->notices()->create($notice);
}
```

Comment: I actually just fixed the issue by doing `$notice = \Auth::user()->notices()->create($notice);`, but this also works.

Comment: Yes, the `$notice` in the first line is an array not the `object` returned by `create` method.